# How do we force a group name change to propagate to Google Apps Email accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-groups

We changed a google group name from "Old Name" to "New Name", but only new recipients in Gmail for Google Apps see "New Name" when composing an email to the group, or receiving an email from the group. Everybody who has already communicated through the group still sees "Old Name."

This seems like a failure to refresh problem in Gmail. Is there some way to force refresh the group name? It is particularly bad because "Old Name" is ambiguous when Google chooses to display only the first name portion of the name.

Update (to answer some questions):

- We did not change the email address, only the name.
- Group name was changed 1 month ago, but problem persists.
- Users do not have the group saved in My Contacts (verified with peers).
- The group is managed from the admin console.

Comment: How can you possibly know if users have the group-name saved in their personal Contacts?

Comment: It's a group used by my company, we verified yesterday.

Comment: I have never done a change as the one you describe, but in my experience, many changes in a Google Apps domain does take some time before it is visible to all users. How long ago did you change the group name?

Comment: More than 1 month ago.

Comment: I can't answer because I don't have enough reputation points.  However, there is another place that the name is cached besides settings.  It only seems to apply to one sending account but I thought I would mention still.  In desktop version, double click on the email address after typing it in and it will give you the option to "Change Name."  Once you change it there, it will be changed whenever you compose a message.  GMail needs an option to delete name change as well as an option to show that it's using the changed name, because now there's no indication that the name is cached elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, we were unable to find a fix for this issue, so we created a new group and moved everybody into it. This was doable as the group was internal to our organization and everyone was willing to migrate.